# Finding correspondences with INDEX in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on an Excel sheet and I have to pickup all matches according to some criterias.

This is an example:

```
a   b   r   abr
a   c   m   acm
a   c   r   acr
a   d   m   adm
a   e   m   aem
a   e   r   aer
a   f   r   afr
a   f   m   afm
a   d   r   adr
a   b   m   abm
```

[image]

So, it must return every code with "r" or "m' at the end. As I might insert new codes, this must be quite dynamic. I am currently using this formula

```
={IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$D$10;SMALL(IF($C$1:$C$10="r";ROW($A$1:$A$10));ROW(A1));4);IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$D$10;SMALL(IF($C$1:$C$10="m";ROW($A$1:$A$10));ROW(A1));4);""))}
```

It returns the codes with "r", which is first in my formula, but doesn't work with "m". It seems the problem is related on how to return the k-th value of the matrix even if I change the tables's order.

Any ideia?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a little unclear - what are you trying to return? Is column D where your formula is going, or are you using the group at the bottom of A?

Comment: I don't really know what is going on in the formula/how it's working, but why can't you use `OR()`? `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$D$10,SMALL(IF(OR($C$1:$C$10="m",$C$1:$C$10="r"),ROW($A$1:$A$10)),ROW(A1)),4),"")`?

Comment: @BruceWayne Array formulas do not like OR() or AND()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer AGGREGATE with INDEX instead of SMALL:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$1:$D$10;AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW($C$1:$C$10)/(($C$1:$C$10="r")+($C$1:$C$10="m"));ROW(1:1)));"")
```

---

If you want to use the array form of SMALL:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$1:$D$10;SMALL(IF(($C$1:$C$10="r")+($C$1:$C$10="m");ROW($C$1:$C$10));ROW(1:1))),"")
```

or

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$1:$D$10;SMALL(IF(($C$1:$C$10="r");ROW($C$1:$C$10);IF(($C$1:$C$10="m");ROW($C$1:$C$10)));ROW(1:1)));"")
```

Remember that the Small formula versions need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: With AGGREGATE it did work and also the ones SMALL. I liked the first with small, so simple and clever!

Comment: @RodrigoSchneiderBender please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.